# Jenkins failing cucumber junit tests

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber

I have a cucumber tests that all run successfully on my local but some of the tests failed when run with Jenkins stating unable to locate elements on all the tests that failed. I have re-run these tests many times locally and all passed. Also build is showing unstable in cmd after jenkin execution.

Comment: You tryed to use WebDriverWait?

Comment: Do you run it in container? If so maybe you run out of memory - check `--disable-dev-shm-usage` (chrome) or assign more memory to container

Comment: I didn't run it from a container.

Comment: You might want to try adding conditional awaits, like waiting for elements to be visible. Without further information this will be hard to debug.

Comment: The tests has webdriverwait already, as this is being used when running it from my local.